# my laptop sata drive pin on the motherboard is broken

Tags: windows-7

my laptop sata drive pin on the motherboard is broken. I decided to solder it but i don't know if I can work by soldering it or not. actually I don't know what to do because he the machine does not detect any hard drive. Please any help?

Comment: You will either need to replace the motherboard or repair the pin.  It might not work.  But those are your only two options.  If you don't have the technical skills to repair it, I would find a replacement motherboard, people sell laptops with say a broken screen for parts all the time on sites like eBay.

Comment: Your question is being given down votes because it is so poorly written. You have not actually asked a question or given enough detail for anyone to effectively help you. Edit your question to include details. No one here is able to "virtually" solder it for you, so what answers are you hoping for?

Answer (score 1):

If you are mentioning about the L shaped piece of plastic in the sata pin in your motherboard ,you may use L piece from any old sata connector and a plastic bonder to fix you problem.  since every SATA connector is built to the same specs for the sake of backwards compatibility any L piece from any old sata connector would do the task.

I hope all motherboards come with atleast two SATA ports , if you use your CD-ROM drives devices occasionally , you may switch your hard disk with your CD-ROM device.I have seen motherboards with 4 sata pins in PC , but I am not sure about laptops.

You may want to buy a new motherboard if you are unsuccessful in repairing the pin.As user Ramhound suggested in the comments you may find spare parts of computers from sites like eBay.

(IMHO trying to fix the motherboard if you are not an experienced user is not advised or supervision of an experienced user id advised.)